# Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I have this .htaccess which rewrites a URL for me, it hasn't been working.

If I check `var/logs/apache2/error_log`, it says :-

```
[[Sun Jul 16 18:22:28.958099 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4237] [client ::1:54344] /Library/WebServer/Documents/getcv/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

What might be wrong? I even have `rewrite_module` enabled in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule request_module libexec/apache2/mod_request.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule filter_module libexec/apache2/mod_filter.so
```

Here's the **.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /my_profile\.php\?username=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ my_profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is almost a year old but I too ran into this problem and came upon this question while searching for answer.

I found the answer here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

In my case, I did the following (I run Ubuntu 16.x.x)

1. edited `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` - I added

   ```bash
    <Directory /var/www/html/api>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
   ```
2. In `/var/www/html/api/.htaccess`, I added

   ```bash
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
   FallbackResource /index.php

   ErrorDocument 404 /api404.php
   ```

   Notice that `api404.php` is simply my own custom 404 page to present visitor with a custom/controlled message in lieu of standard out.
3. I then, as noted in the above link, enabled module_override by running the following commands:

   ```bash
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

After doing above steps, my URI `https://api.example.com/rfq/new` redirected to my `index.php` script and I was able to handle parsing of URI as intended.

Answer (score -1):

This superuser command line enables mod rewrite in Apache2

## a2enmod rewrite

Comment: First, the question says they already have rewrite enabled, second, the highest voted answer here already contains this command.